# Alarm clock OS X with automator and password on wake up

Tags: macos, productivity, alarm

As there is no built in alarm clock in OS X, like in IOS, is there any way to set alarm clock via automator (playlist in iTunes), when Mac is in sleep mode and login password is required?

Answer (score 1):

There is an scheduler for sleeping and waking up OS X in `System Preferences` > `Energy Saver` > `Schedule...`.

Unlike the alarm in the iOS you can set timers in `Automator` with `Pause` action. It will work even your Mac is asleep. Playing iTunes playlist does not require password for the running Automator workflow. You can make a workflow of pausing until your preferred time and then play your playlist. You should set the scheduler to wake up before the pause passed.

After starting the workflow you can sleep your Mac.

Comment: So to set Automator timers do i have to set Schedule in Energy Saver or it will work simply with Automator script?

Comment: Yes you should set the schedule. Automator itself can not wake your computer up.